# Why to remember state in `application` scope in Compose Desktop?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

One of Compose Desktop examples uses the following [snippet](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/examples/notepad/src/main/kotlin/main.kt) as entry point:

```kotlin
fun main() = application {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalAppResources provides rememberAppResources()) {
        NotepadApplication(rememberApplicationState())
    }
}
```

Here's the definition of `rememberApplicationState()`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun rememberApplicationState() = remember {
    NotepadApplicationState().apply {
        newWindow()
    }
}
```

I don't really understand why to remember a top-level app's state here. As far as I understand, recomposition is not expected neither for `application` nor for `CompositionLocalProvider`. Can we just pass an instance of `NotepadApplicationState` without any consequences?